# Simplest way to build webhook converter in Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building a small tool (no UI) that will accept webhooks from several services, reformat the content, and then send standardized content to another webhook.

Example: Stripes webhook has lots of raw data, but I want to ping another webhook with a summary. So I want to take the raw data stripe sends me, reformat it to a simple string, and then send to another webhook.

I imagine the script doing this:

```
# 1. receive webhook sent to URL with ?service=stripe param
# 2. parse URL to get service param
# 3. parse data received in payload
# 4. use some of the data received in new string
# 5. send string to new webhook
```

I'd love to host this on GAE. I've built lots of projects with Django, but since this doesn't need a UI or database that seems heavy. I'd love any help. I've got the GAE project set up, and this going:

```
import web #using web.py
import logging

urls = (
    "/.*", "hooks",
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hooks:
    # 1. DONE receive webhook sent to URL with ?service=stripe param
    def POST(self):

        # 2. parse URL to get service param        
        # ...
        # service_name = [parsed service name]

        # 3. DONE parse data received in payload
        data = web.data()
        logging.info(data)

        # 4. DONE use some of the data received in new string
        # (I've got the reformatting scripts already written) 
        # data_to_send = reformat(data, service_name)

        # 5. send data_to_send as payload to new webhook
        # new_webhook_url = 'http://example.com/1823123/'
        # CURL for new webhook is: curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://example.com/1823123/' -d '{"text": data_to_send}'

        return 'OK'

app = app.gaerun()
```

So on GAE, is there a preferred method for (2) parsing incoming URL and (5) sending a webhook?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with web.py.  Many GAE apps are based on webapp2.

For parsing URLs with webapp2, you create [routes](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html).  Here is a simple route that I created for processing PayPal IPNs:

```
    (r'/ipn/(\S+)/(\w+)', website.ProcessIPN)
```

I then have a handler that processes this route:

```
class ProcessIPN(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, user, secret):
        payload = json.loads(self.request.body)
        ...
```

The route is a regular expression that captures two parts of the URL and these are passed as the two parameters of the handler (user and secret).  Assuming your payload is JSON so you can easily get it with webapp2 as indicated above.

For sending a webhook, you need to use [urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/issue-requests).

Given how simple your use case is, I recommend not using web.py and instead using webapp2.

Comment: Would I use webapp2 to parse the incoming URL, as well as the payload (2 & 3)?

Comment: @Brenden, updated answer to show how you get the payload with webapp2.